# How to remove leading spaces in a dynamic char array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc

I need to remove leading spaces from dynamic character array in C. My application almost works, but it leaves just one space at the beginning. How to get rid of all leading spaces from the given text? I should not use functions from `string.h`. Heres my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int mystrlen(char *tab)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(tab[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

char* ex6(char *tab)
{
    int spaces = 0, i, j = 0, s = 0;
    for(i=0; tab[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (tab[i] == ' ')
            spaces ++;
        else
            break;
    }

    spaces -= 1;

    char *w = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * (mystrlen(tab) - spaces + 1));
    for(i=0; tab[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (tab[i] == ' ')
        {
            ++ s;
        }
        if(s > spaces)
        {
            w[j] = tab[i];
            j ++;
        }
    }
    w[j] = 0;
    return w;
}

int main()
{
    char txt[] = "        Hello World";

    char *w = ex6(txt);
    printf("%s\n", w);

    free(w);
    w = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: count them, and use `memmove`.

Comment: @iharob: but I should not use functions from `string.h`

Comment: [Thou shalt not cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: You didn't mention that in the question.

Comment: You're already using `strlen()`, which is defined in `<string.h>`, so you need to decide exactly what the constraints are here.

Answer (score 4):

Modifying the string in-place allows stripping leading spaces in a fairly compact manner since you don't need to calculate the length of the result string:

```
/* No includes needed for ltrim. */

void ltrim( char *s )
{
    const char *t = s;
    while ( *t && *t == ' ' )
        ++t;

    while ( ( *s++ = *t++ ) )
        ;
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char txt[] = "        Hello World";

    ltrim(txt);
    printf("%s\n", txt);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `spaces -= 1` line. You go back 1 space left.

Comment: whe I removed this, I got only ` World` word

Answer (score 1):

You can just move the `tab` pointer forward using pointer arithmetic, and then count the remaining characters in the string, then allocate space for the new string and copy each character to the new allocated space.

This is how to do it without `strings.h`

```
char* ex6(char *tab)
{
    int   i;
    char *w;
    while ((*tab == ' ') && (*tab != '\0'))
        tab++;
    w = malloc(mystrlen(tab) + 1);
    i = 0;
    while (*tab != '\0')
        w[i++] = *tab++;
    w[i] = '\0';
    return w;
}
```

Comment: Both `memmove` as well as `strdup` are from `string.h` which is not available to the OP.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I know, but he used `strlen` in his code, and didn't mention that `string.h` was forbidden.